# Switch to a specific clojure version from REPL

Tags: clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I have two apps `app1.jar` and `app2.jar`, with Clojure 1.2 included in `app1` and Clojure 1.4 in `app2`.

When I run:

```
java -cp app1.jar:app2.jar clojure.main
```

to open a REPL, it uses Clojure 1.2. Is there a way to switch to Clojure 1.4?

Answer (score 3):

As with many such question the anser is **[use leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen)** lein2 has a [profiles feature](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/doc/PROFILES.md) that lets you properly handle multiple versions of clojure. This is especially useful because the clojure.contrib libraries are very different between those two versions. It took me longer to type this sentence than to install, configure and get a project started with leiningen. It really is worth it.

In practice you will need to have two instances of clojure running, one with each profile (version) and you can then either have two REPLs (one attached to each) or one repl (using nrepl) that you switch back and forth.

There is an unfortunate amount of old documentation on the net for Clojure that predates mass adoption of Leiningen.

Comment: I do use leiningen, I'll look into profiles. Specifically, I am using jark to keep a persistent JVM. The jark-server is built with Clojure 1.2 which gives me the same version in REPL and also for any app I try "proxying" through jark. Any ideas on how to run server with 1.2 and app with 1.4?